# uwp listview ItemSource not getting data with x:Bind

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, uwp

I have done this a thousand times before in many scenarios with gridviews and listviews, but this time due to some unknown reason it seems that it is not working.

I am just creating a simple **ListView** in my **UWP** app and then binding its **ItemSource** with **x:Bind** to an **ObservableCollection< Folder > Source** where **Folder** is just a class. I have checked with a breakpoint that even after instantiating the **ViewModel** the **ItemSource** of the listview is null. But if I set the ItemSource in code behind instead of binding it, then it works just fine. I am using basic **MVVM** pattren.

**CODE**

**LibraryPage.xaml**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Source}" x:Name="AdaptiveView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:VideoFolder">
                    <controls:DropShadowPanel>
                        <Grid Height="200" Width="200">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Source="{x:Bind   Thumbnail,Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Title}" Grid.Row="1"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**LibraryPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class LibraryPage : Page
{
    public LibraryViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public LibraryPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        ViewModel = new LibraryViewModel(KnownFolders.VideosLibrary);
        var source = AdaptiveView.ItemsSource;
    }
}
```

**LibraryViewModel.cs**

```
 public class LibraryViewModel : Observable
{
    public ObservableCollection<VideoFolder> Source { get; set; }

    public StorageFolder MainFolder { get; set; }
    public LibraryViewModel(StorageFolder mainFolder)
    {
        Source = new ObservableCollection<VideoFolder>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Source.Add(new Folder { Title = "touseef" + i });
        }
        // MainFolder = mainFolder;
        //FillUpFolders();
        //FillUpFiles();
    }
}
```

I am providing my app project here so that if anyone wants to run it and test it on their own machine the can, problem is only on the LibraryPage, so you can just run the app and navigate to the **Library** and see that I am not getting any items in my listview. project was created using **Windows Template Studio** and some elements in the app are from nuget package **UWP Community Toolkit**.

Please have a look and let me know why I am not getting any items in my ListView. here is the link for the project.

https://github.com/touseefbsb/ListViewItemSourceBug

**min target** creators update

**target** Fall creators update

**my device**  insider build 17120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in how you are initializing your view model on that page. The view model is getting initialized after your ListView is loaded so the binding sees that the `source` is null at this stage. What I usually do is this:

In the page XAML, initialize your ViewModel like this:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <LibraryViewModel />
</Page.DataContext>
```

The above code will ensure your view model is initialized with the rest of the page. Then in the c# Code Behind of that page do this:

```
public LibraryViewModel ViewModel => (LibraryViewModel)this.DataContext;
```

now when your page is loaded, the View model is already loaded along with it.

Next, in the XAML binding for your list view, set the mode to be OneWay (i think this is optional in this case since your `Source` is initialized in the View Model constructor, but I am adding this here just to be sure):

```
<ListView ItemsSource={x:Bind ViewModel.Source, Mode=OneWay} .... />
```

Comment: but I have to add the folder to the ViewModel constructor as well , because I need a drill in feature on this page, so that is why each time I navigate to this page the folder will be different, so how can I do this scenario?

Comment: I havent tried to initialize it in xaml yet, but I tried to make the source observable with Observable class which implements InotifyProperty changed, and then I made mode=Oneway as well, in the xaml. but that wasnt working either, so everytime the Source property changes, it shoudve notified so it should work even when i was doing it in OnNavigatedTo method, but why wasnt it working that way?

Comment: ok I tried your suggested way and it is working, but is there a better way to use this? I mean where I can provide some folder into the constructor as well on OnNavigatedTo method? and If I have some complex async methods in the constructor to load files and folders, I dnt think that loading it in the xaml would be an efficient way? because it is an observableCollection and each item can easily be added 1 by 1, I mean that should be the right way to do it.

Comment: @touseef in the ViewModel create a new public method that accepts the folder parameter and move the constructor code to that method. Basically, leave the ViewModel class with a default empty constructor and in the ```OnNavigatedTo``` simply call that new method with the folder you want to use.